# Firebase: deploy a second function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I need to deploy a second cloud function. I've noticed than when I deploy it with `firebase deploy --only functions:secondFunction`, the process skips the 'functions: updating Node.js 16 function app(us-central1)...' step and says deploy complete yet the cloud function remains unchanged. Kindly help

Comment: I have provided an answer below.please check

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in this github [thread1](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/312) & [thread2](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/683),  it is a result of the nature of Typescript's ability to import things outside of the obvious source tree.

> typescript is building into `lib/functions/index.js` instead of
> `lib/index.js`, thus `package.json` is pointing to the wrong file, and
> deploying an older compiled .js file.
>
> So you can either
>
> - edit "main" in the package.json `"main":"lib/index.js"`  to `"main":"lib/functions/src/index.js"`  to point at the new location
> - remove  imports and rebuild, then it went back to the building it at `lib/index.js`

You can also check this  stackoverflow [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71200992/18265638) to properly export the function and deploy in javascript